# composition of 2 differentiable function is differentiable

Tags: calculus, derivatives, proof-writing

How can I prove that if $f$ and $g$ are differentiable, then the composite $f(g(x))$ is also differentiable? It is not very clear to me. I did see some other questions here about the topic but I didn't quite understood the answers and why they were true.

Comment: What part of those answers didn't you understand ?